Can I get the resource name of an aliased data source?
Since the actual name of the flat file diverged from the purpose,
I gave the data store an easy-to-understand name and the actual file name as the resource name.
Is it possible to get the resource name from the datastore name?
ODI12c, database is Oracle.
Try to odiRef.getObjectName(...) to variable, but it was the alias that was retrieved.

Try the getSrcTablesList() or getTargetTable() with pattern attriute RES_NAME. I believe that retrieves the filename.

Thanks for the comment!
I guess I am still learning more about ODI and how to use its API.
I will continue to learn so that I can use your advice.
